# Remove selection on one WPF control when another control is active

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In a WPF application I have TreeView and ListBox controls, both of which have their `SelectedItem` dependency property bound to the same property in the view model. So when I have selected items in both controls and try to access that view model's property it behaves unpredictably. Is it possible to remove selection on one control when item is selected in another one?

Sample code (`CurrentNamedObject` is a view model property and the same for both controls):

```
<controls:XTreeView  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <wpf:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.CurrentNamedObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
...

<ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.CurrentNamedObject}">
...
```

**Update:**

The basic idea behind this is following:
There are two types of objects which implement the same interface (IModifiable). One type of object has descendant objects so I chose to display it in a treeview; another one is a plain object, so I display it in a listbox. Now, I have a toolbox with modification commands that are applicable to both types of object, so I bound both objects to the same property. In essence, I want, for example, to call Rename method on the selected item regardless of whether it's a treeview or a listbox item.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea... if you tell us what you are trying to achieve overall, we might be able to suggest a better way to achieve it.

Comment: If you make both SelectedItem bindings OneWay, there shouldnt be any conflicts, but you can't change the SelectedItems from code-behind.